# Adding code from a multidimensional javascript array to html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website that should allow you to filter pictures using javascript. You select a search criteria using an html dropdown list.

I now want to insert the code of the image into the html file and honestly have no idea how to do it.

Here's an example of a dropdown list:

```
<select id="HairColor" onchange="getCharacters()">
    <option value="default">Select Hair Color</option>
    <option value=""></option>                          
    <option value="brown">Brown</option>
    <option value="fair">Fair</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Here's the javascript file:

```
var ika = ["anime1", "female", "blue", "blue", "genki", "<12", '<a href="character.html"><div id="onecard"><img src="characters/Ika/ika.jpg" height="280" width="180"><div id="description">Ika Musume<br>Shinryaku! Ika Musume</div></div></a>', true];
var hotaru = ["anime2", "female", "brown", "brown", "other", "12-24", '<a href="character.html"><div id="onecard"><img src="characters/Non/hotaru.jpg" height="280" width="180"><div id="description">Hotaru Ichijou<br>Non Non Biyori</div></div></a>', true];
var suguru = ["anime2", "male", "brown", "black", "other", "12-24", '<a href="character.html"><div id="onecard"><img src="characters/Non/suguru.jpg" height="280" width="180"><div id="description">Suguru Koshigaya<br>Non Non Biyori</div></div></a>', true];


var characters = [ika, hotaru, suguru];

function getCharacters() {

    var selection = [document.getElementById("Anime").value, document.getElementById("Gender").value, document.getElementById("HairColor").value, document.getElementById("EyeColor").value, document.getElementById("Personality").value, document.getElementById("AgeRange").value];

    for(i = 0; i < characters.length; i++){
        characters[i][7] = true;
        for(j = 0; j < selection.length && characters[i][7] != false; j++){
            if (characters[i][j] != selection[j] && selection[j] != "default"){
                characters[i][7] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    var count = 0;
    var output;
    for(i = 0; i < characters.length; i++){
        if(characters[i][7] == true){
            output[count] = characters[i];
            count++;
        }
    }

    var element = document.getElementById("cards");
    for(i=0; i<output.length; i++){
        element.innerHTML = output[i][6];
    }
}
```

I want the code on the six array place to be output in the "cards" div but it doesn't do anything. I also want it to start all over again every time you make a new selection, so that old images don't stay in the div.

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong? I honestly have no clue and I am at my wits end.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Added missing `,` in one of the character arrays. Still doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: Well your `suguru` array is erroring for one. Missing `,` before the `true` at the end.

Comment: Do you plan on using any of the info in the original arrays other than sorting? Like do you plan on displaying info about your characters on the cards?

Comment: You're using global for-loop counters, that's always a code smell. Use `for (var i = ... )` You also aren't appending HTML, you're overriding it each time in the last for-loop. Use `element.innerHTML += output[i][6]` to append. Anddddd... `output` is not an array, and I think you want it to be. Declare it as `var output = [];` instead.

Comment: Can you add a working example that can recreate the issue? Either with a Stack snippet or jsFiddle or the like?

Comment: @Press: I fixed the `,` and also changed what Cory suggested but it still doesn't to seem working. I am trying to output the code on the sixth array slot of the character arrays.

Comment: I'm working on an answer, I have it almost done, it's outputting the images but loops too many times.
**Edit** What I have so far [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1dzxsrp/4/)
**Edit Again** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1dzxsrp/5/) does this look like what you're going for, @Fruitypoopy?

Comment: @Press: YES! This is pretty much exactly what I am looking for. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fy2ekos/) you requested.

Comment: The code I provided isn't perfect, and it loops through one of the objects twice. I can fix this an add it as an answer shortly.

Comment: @Press: I would really appreciate that. That's a lot dude. You are my hero.

Comment: @Cory: Oops, I accidentally replied to Cory with the fiddle instead of you. There you go: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fy2ekos/). I hope this is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was tough but I think we managed.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wc5o2dc1/3/)

Okay so to start off we switch from just an array for the characters to an object so we can use key:value pairs. This will come into play. Also instead of creating a `selections` array we ditch that completely. Each dropdown will provide us with everything we need. Then we create a simple loop to go through each character in the `characters` array and look at their `key` and their `key`'s value and see if it matches the sender's value ( `obj.value` ).

`getCharacters(this, 'anime')` - `this` being the object and will be how we get `obj.value` later. `anime` is our `type` variable used in the function which is also the `key` in our `key:value` pair.

Also at the beginning of the function we're doing some resets so when you select something new it will clear the cards and redisplay the proper characters.

```js
var ika = { anime: 'anime1', gender: 'female', hair: 'blue', eyes: 'blue', personality: 'genki', age: '<12', data: '<a href="character.html"><div id="onecard"><img src="http://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/13/107764.jpg" height="280" width="180"><div id="description">Ika Musume<br>Shinryaku! Ika Musume</div></div></a>', shown: false };

var hotaru = { anime: "anime2", gender: "female", hair: "brown", eyes: "brown", personality: "other", age: "12-24", data: '<a href="character.html"><div id="onecard"><img src="http://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/15/222839.jpg" height="280" width="180"><div id="description">Hotaru Ichijou<br>Non Non Biyori</div></div></a>', shown: false };

var suguru = { anime: "anime2", gender: "male", hair: "brown", eyes: "black", personaility: "other", age: "12-24", data: '<a href="character.html"><div id="onecard"><img src="http://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/characters/3/223393.jpg" height="280" width="180"><div id="description">Suguru Koshigaya<br>Non Non Biyori</div></div></a>', shown: false };


var characters = [ika, hotaru, suguru];

function getCharacters(obj, type) {
    
    for ( var y = 0; y < characters.length; y++ ) {              
        characters[y]['shown'] = false;
    }    
    
    var output = "";
    var cards = document.getElementById("cards");
    cards.innerHTML = "";
    console.log(characters.length + ' ' + obj.value + ' ' + type);

    for ( var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++ ) {
        //for ( var y = 0; y < characters[i].length; y++ ) {
            console.log(i + ' ' + characters[i][type]);
            if ( characters[i][type] == obj.value ) {                
                characters[i]['shown'] = true;
            }
        //}
    }
    
    for ( var z = 0; z < characters.length; z++ ) {
        if ( characters[z]['shown'] ) {
            output += '<br />' + characters[z]['data'];   
        }
    }

    cards.innerHTML += output;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="top">
            <div id="banner">
                <img src="banner.png" alt="Banner" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            <div id="dropdowns">
                <form>
                    <select id="Anime" onchange="getCharacters(this, 'anime')">
                        <option value="default">Select Anime</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="anime1">Gochuumon wa Usagi Desu ka?</option>
                        <option value="anime2">Non Non Biyori</option>
                        <option value="anime3">Shinryaku! Ika Musume</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="Gender" onchange="getCharacters(this, 'gender')">
                        <option value="default">Select Gender</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                        <option value="other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="HairColor" onchange="getCharacters(this)">
                        <option value="default">Select Hair Color</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
                        <option value="fair">Fair</option>
                        <option value="black">Black</option>
                        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="EyeColor" onchange="getCharacters(this)">
                        <option value="default">Select Eye Color</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
                        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                        <option value="green">Green</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="Personality" onchange="getCharacters(this)">
                        <option value="default">Select Personality</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="tsundere">Tsundere</option>
                        <option value="genki">Genki</option>
                        <option value="yandere">Yandere</option>
                        <option value="other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="AgeRange" onchange="getCharacters(this)">
                        <option value="default">Select Age Range</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="<12">&lt;12</option>
                        <option value="12-24">12-24</option>
                        <option value=">24">>24</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="cards"></div>
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much for this. I really appreciate it, dude. Seriously. I could kiss you right now.

Comment: Uh, not needed, but thank you. Post questions if you have any and I'll be around.